# Frother got burn in base and won’t heat properly

Tags: flavor, espresso-machine, equipment

The Frother as pictured got a milk (I think) burn at bottom. It doesn’t work(warm) well. The light start blinking and we have to run it again to get acceptable/preferred temperature. We tried washing it away but it won’t go.

Is there a way to fix the milk frother? 
[image: burned base]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see from the photo, the Teflon coating has been swelled. If this is the case, it is an indicator that your frother have over-heated and stay in that state for a very long time.

I assume, the heater coil switched on and off to keep the temperature stable for long. Finally, the coil burnt out itself. I don't think you can do much. Even if you change the coil, the swelled Teflon is not very healthy. I wouldn't use it anymore.

Also, I think you're lucky that this did not cause any serious damage.

Comment: What kind of damage? We still use it. What is a coil? If it’s the rotating thing that work too but not warming or making Forthe as it use to. What is Teflon coating. If that is not useable how can I make milk forthe manually?

Comment: Damage: If the device turned on and off for a long period, it might have burn your kitchen. It is better as it burnt itself out before causing fire. Teflon: the slippery surface is a coating on the actual material. If it swelled it may cause health problems (cancer?) in the long run. Manual froth: I think your best option is to use a French press. It is very practical when you don't have any device. See: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/how-do-i-make-that-frothy-milk-that-coffee-shops-use-to-make-lattes/2460#2460

Comment: I tried scrapping the burn area off the Teflon, the Teflon isn't swelled. I was able to scrap to a lot the burn. In essence the warming time was extended to almost normal but still it blinked before stopping. So you reckon, it has reached end of its life and need replacement?

Comment: If heating time returns to normal, it looks like the heater has been isolated by the remains. Clean it thoroughly.