# Keeping milk frother in shape

Tags: cleaning, froth, freshness

We recently got new Milk Frother and I do not intend to it have residue which burns up as described in [this](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/frother-got-burn-in-base-and-won-t-heat-properly) question. What are ways to keep it clean after a day of use. I heard everytime you use it, wash it, if that is true just rinse will do or proper wash with fairy and sponge (which sound hectic) given In office.

Answer (score -1):

For someone who works with high commercial grade espresso machines, I clean my shop's machine once a day before closing. There really isn't enough downtime in the day to deep clean the machine. For someone like yourself who might use it once or twice a day, just make sure that you always wipe it down with a damp rag and purge it a time or two for a couple seconds. If you really are concerned about it always being clean, buy some Cafiza. It'll keep your frother super clean.

Hope this helps!

https://www.webstaurantstore.com/urnex-12-esp12-20-20-oz-cafiza-espresso-machine-cleaning-powder/588ESP1220.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=CjwKCAiAy-_iBRAaEiwAYhSlA89ztllMujcfFKnhSgahUDlT2wpWRh9g7gS37eHBVaF_3zyMx3GfJhoCvjIQAvD_BwE